# BES doubt as web server

Tags: web-services, blackberry

I am developing a Blackberry website. I am asked by a client that my applications' http request should go through BES. How to do that ? Is it possible to design my php/html pages such that the urls always pass through BES and are served from my web server ?

thanks

Comment: Take a look at getting the MDS working. This will proxy all http requests

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at getting the MDS working, this will proxy all http requests via the bes